# How to convert single column data into multiple columns in python dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame (`df`) with column `col1` which has many rows and there are rows with a common string (`Collection of numbers are`) and ending with different numbers(`001, 002, 005`). I want to extract the rows between two string (`Collection of numbers are 002` to `Collection of numbers are 003`) and assign them to new column with same row name (`Collection of numbers are 002`)

```
    col1
0   Collection of numbers are 002
1   53
2   20
3   56
4   Collection of numbers are 003
5   236
6   325
7   Collection of numbers are 005
8   96
9   23
10  63
```

I want to convert the how above data frame to the following format.

```
0   Collection of numbers are 002   Collection of numbers are 003   Collection of numbers are 005
1   53                              236                              96
2   20                              325                              23
3   56                                                               63
```

Note: No repeated numbers

Comment: can you have several times the same number (like 002)? if yes you want the values to be in the same final column?

Comment: @Ben.T no repeated numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try `ffill` and some basic resphaping using `str.split`

```
df['headers'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(Collection.*)').ffill()


df1 = df[~df['col1'].str.contains('Collection')].copy()


df1.groupby('headers').agg(','.join)['col1'].str.split(',',expand=True).T.rename_axis('',axis='columns')
```

out:

```
  Collection of numbers are 002 Collection of numbers are 003  \
0                            53                           236   
1                            20                           325   
2                            56                          None   

  Collection of numbers are 005  
0                            96  
1                            23  
2                            63
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `set_index` and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). I steal the idea of [@Datanovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61253602/9274732) for extracting the name of the future columns and use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the future index numbers:

```
arrCollection = df['col1'].str.extract('(Collection.*)').ffill()[0].to_numpy()
df_f = df.set_index([df.groupby(arrCollection)['col1'].cumcount()-1,
                     arrCollection])['col1']\
         .unstack().iloc[1:,:]

print (df_f)
  Collection 002 Collection 003 Collection 005
0             53            236             96
1             20            325             23
2             56            NaN             63
```

Note: the name of the columns will be like in your example, I did not use the exact same input

Comment: very clever with cumcount, I wanted to use unstack but couldn't figure it out with my duplicated index (:

Comment: @Datanovice thanks, I was a bit lost when creating the name of the columns before I see your `str.extract` ;) and by the way, you should consider changing your pseudo, you are not really a novice anymore haha

Comment: Once I reach 10k I will change it  =)

Answer (score 0):

in

```
                    col1
0   c of numbers are 002
1                      1
2                      2
3                      3
4   c of numbers are 003
5                     55
6                     66
7   c of numbers are 005
8                     45
9                     23
10                    12
11                   456
12                    56
```

```
for_concat = []
col = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if "numbers" in str(r["col1"]):
        if col:
            for_concat.append(pd.DataFrame(col,columns=[col_name]))
            col_name = r["col1"]
            col = []
        else:
            col_name = r["col1"]
    else:
        col.append(r["col1"])
for_concat.append(pd.DataFrame(col,columns=[col_name]))
out = pd.concat(for_concat, axis =1)
```

out:

```
   c of numbers are 002  c of numbers are 003  c of numbers are 005
0                   1.0                  55.0                    45
1                   2.0                  66.0                    23
2                   3.0                   NaN                    12
3                   NaN                   NaN                   456
4                   NaN                   NaN                    56
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Datanovic seems good.
An alternative solution would be following function:

```
def extract_columns(df, column, common_string):
    df_list = df[column].tolist()
    df_new = pd.DataFrame()
    row_indices = []
    cols = []
    for ind, elem in enumerate(df_list):
        if common_string in str(elem):
            row_indices.append(ind)
            cols.append(elem)

    row_indices.append(len(df_list))

    for ind, col in enumerate(cols): 
        df_new[col] = pd.Series(df_list[row_indices[ind]+1:row_indices[ind+1]])

    return df_new
```

So with your example dataframe you will get following result when calling the function `extract_columns(df, 'col1', 'Collection of numbers are')`

```
   Collection of numbers are 002  Collection of numbers are 003  Collection of numbers are 005
0                             53                          236.0                             96
1                             20                          325.0                             23
2                             56                            NaN                             63
```